# .html file extensions load fine even when set to redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-extension

I have the following 2 lines in my global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute("myTest1", "test", new { 
   controller = "Home", action = "Page", id = "Home" 
});
routes.MapRoute("myTest2", "test.html", new {
   controller = "Home", action = "Page", id = "Home" });
```

The first line above works perfectly, and both lines work when testing locally. The problem comes when putting this on my live server. The second line goes to a 404, as does any other that ends with .html

I really don't understand why it works locally, yet not online.

Any advice would be great. Thanks

--- EDIT ---

I have looked in IIS but i'm not sure the problem lies there.  I tried uploading a html file "test.html" and the page loads perfectly even though its set to redirect.

Comment: Are you using a II6 in your live system? What server do you use locally?

Answer (score 0):

The problem Is with the way dots are treated in general.  Have a look at these two related posts.

[ASP.NET MVC Url Route supporting (dot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273987/asp-net-mvc-url-route-supporting-dot)

[Routing on IIS6 With Decimal In Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530827/routing-on-iis6-with-decimal-in-route)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to make a lot of sense, however I now have a 500 error instead of a 404.  So it has done something, but unsure what...